# Can't decrypt NSData when running BGProcessingTask

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsdata, rncryptor

I setup everything to run some code in the background when my app isn't active. I use BGProcessingTask.

When I Pause the program execution, and enter the command `e -l objc -- (void)[[BGTaskScheduler sharedScheduler] _simulateLaunchForTaskWithIdentifier:@"com.myApp.processing"]`
it tests the Process and runs my code, but it doesn't finish the job when it reaches the code to decrypt my data. I use [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor-objc) to decrypt the data, but it seems like it doesn't want to run when my app is in the background.

**This is the code I run:**

```
- (void)nvmDoubleDecryptedAES256DataWithSecurityKey:(nonnull NSString*)theSecurityKey WithMasterPasswordKey:(nonnull NSString*)theMasterPassword WithCompletion:(void (^_Nullable)(NSData* _Nullable decryptedData, NSError* _Nullable error))completionBlock {
NSError *firstStatus, *secondStatus;
NSLog(@"AR - 111");
NSData *mpDecryptedData = [RNDecryptor decryptData:self withPassword:theMasterPassword error:&firstStatus];
NSLog(@"AR - 112");
if ((mpDecryptedData) && (!firstStatus)) {
    NSData *skDecryptedData = [RNDecryptor decryptData:mpDecryptedData withPassword:theSecurityKey error:&secondStatus];
    NSLog(@"AR - 113");
    if ((skDecryptedData) && (!secondStatus)) {
        if (completionBlock) completionBlock(skDecryptedData, nil);
    }
    else {
        NSError *errorSecurityKeyIncorrect = [NSError errorWithDomain:[NVMFunctions getBundleIdentifier] code:PRLErrorCodeSecurityKeyIncorrect userInfo:@{NSLocalizedDescriptionKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Security Key is incorrect | Decrypt error: %@", firstStatus]}]; //Keep this error code
        if (completionBlock) completionBlock(nil, errorSecurityKeyIncorrect);
    }
}
else {
    NSError *errorMasterPasswordIncorrect = [NSError errorWithDomain:[NVMFunctions getBundleIdentifier] code:PRLErrorCodeMasterPasswordKeyIncorrect userInfo:@{NSLocalizedDescriptionKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Master Password is incorrect | Decrypt error: %@", secondStatus]}]; //Keep this error code
    if (completionBlock) completionBlock(nil, errorMasterPasswordIncorrect);
}
```

}

But in the logs I see i keeps hanging on `AR - 111` . As soon as i reopen my app is continues with `AR - 112`. It seems like a big issue if I can't decrypt my data in the background...

Does anyone know a fix?

**Full logs:**

```
 (lldb) e -l objc -- (void)[[BGTaskScheduler sharedScheduler] _simulateLaunchForTaskWithIdentifier:@"com.novem.Peral.processing"]
2020-06-03 21:38:06.120568+0200 Peral[14608:3145844] Simulating launch for task with identifier com.novem.Peral.processing
2020-06-03 21:38:14.539735+0200 Peral[14608:3146386] Starting simulated task: <BGProcessingTask: com.novem.Peral.processing>
2020-06-03 21:38:14.580935+0200 Peral[14608:3146383] AR - 111
```

**AppDelegate.m:**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    [self registerBackgroundTaks];

    return YES;
}

- (void)registerBackgroundTaks {
    [[BGTaskScheduler sharedScheduler] registerForTaskWithIdentifier:@"com.novem.Peral.processing" usingQueue:nil launchHandler:^(__kindof BGTask * _Nonnull task) {
        [self handleAppRefresh:task];
    }];
}

- (void)handleAppRefresh:(BGProcessingTask *)task {
    [self scheduleAppRefresh];

    NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    [queue addOperationWithBlock: ^{
        NSString *theSecurityKey = @"key";
        NSString *theMasterPassword = @"passord";
        [self nvmDoubleDecryptedAES256DataWithSecurityKey:theSecurityKey WithMasterPasswordKey:theMasterPassword WithCompletion:^(NSData * _Nullable decryptedData, NSError * _Nullable error) {
            [task setTaskCompletedWithSuccess:!queue.isSuspended];
        }];
    }];


    [task setExpirationHandler:^{
        [queue cancelAllOperations];
    }];
}

- (void)scheduleAppRefresh {
    BGProcessingTaskRequest *request = [[BGProcessingTaskRequest alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"com.novem.Peral.processing"];
    [request setRequiresExternalPower:YES];
    [request setRequiresNetworkConnectivity:YES];
    //[request setEarliestBeginDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:2 * 60]]; //Start after 2 minutes

    NSError *requestError;
    [[BGTaskScheduler sharedScheduler] submitTaskRequest:request error:&requestError];
    if (requestError) NSLog(@"Exception: %@", requestError);
}
```

---

**EDIT**

After looking at the RNCryptor, if found out that it freezes when reaching a certain line.

```
   + (NSData *)keyForPassword:(NSString *)password salt:(NSData *)salt settings:(RNCryptorKeyDerivationSettings)keySettings
{
    NSLog(@"RN - 124831");
  NSMutableData *derivedKey = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:keySettings.keySize];
  NSLog(@"RN - 124832");

  // See Issue #77. V2 incorrectly calculated key for multi-byte characters.
  NSData *passwordData;
  NSLog(@"RN - 124833");
  if (keySettings.hasV2Password) {
      NSLog(@"RN - 1248331");
    passwordData = [NSData dataWithBytes:[password UTF8String] length:[password length]];
  }
  else {
      NSLog(@"RN - 1248332");
    passwordData = [password dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
  }

  // Use the built-in PBKDF2 if it's available. Otherwise, we have our own. Hello crazy function pointer.
  NSLog(@"RN - 124834");
  int result;
  NSLog(@"RN - 124835");
  int (*PBKDF)(CCPBKDFAlgorithm algorithm, const char *password, size_t passwordLen,
               const uint8_t *salt, size_t saltLen,
               CCPseudoRandomAlgorithm prf, uint rounds,
               uint8_t *derivedKey, size_t derivedKeyLen);

    NSLog(@"RN - 124836");
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wunreachable-code"
  PBKDF = CCKeyDerivationPBKDF ?: RN_CCKeyDerivationPBKDF;
#pragma clang diagnostic pop

    NSLog(@"RN - 124837");
  result = PBKDF(keySettings.PBKDFAlgorithm,         // algorithm
                 passwordData.bytes,                 // password
                 passwordData.length,                // passwordLength
                 salt.bytes,                         // salt
                 salt.length,                        // saltLen
                 keySettings.PRF,                    // PRF
                 keySettings.rounds,                 // rounds
                 derivedKey.mutableBytes,            // derivedKey
                 derivedKey.length);                 // derivedKeyLen

    NSLog(@"RN - 124838");
  // Do not log password here
  NSAssert(result == kCCSuccess, @"Unable to create AES key for password: %d", result);

  return derivedKey;
}
```

This is the log I get:

```
2020-06-04 21:37:32.238187+0200 Peral[16824:3659587] RN - 124831
2020-06-04 21:37:32.238507+0200 Peral[16824:3659587] RN - 124832
2020-06-04 21:37:32.238818+0200 Peral[16824:3659587] RN - 124833
2020-06-04 21:37:32.239046+0200 Peral[16824:3659587] RN - 1248332
2020-06-04 21:37:32.239419+0200 Peral[16824:3659587] RN - 124834
2020-06-04 21:37:32.239663+0200 Peral[16824:3659587] RN - 124835
2020-06-04 21:37:32.240287+0200 Peral[16824:3659587] RN - 124836
2020-06-04 21:37:32.240575+0200 Peral[16824:3659587] RN - 124837
```

so it freezes with result = PBKDF....

Comment: Have you added an expiration handler to the `BGTask`? If so, is it getting called? Also, the presence of this completion handler makes me wonder if you’re calling this asynchronously, and if so, are you sure your `setTaskCompleted` is inside the completion handler closure. Bottom line, show us your handling of the `BGTask`, its expiration handler, where you call `setTaskCompleted`, and the full console logs (which, when you call `_simulateLaunchForTaskWithIdentifier`, includes all sorts of useful information).

Comment: Also, for the sake of completeness, you might want to confirm that `decryptData` (a) isn’t trying to open any files ... if it does, you need to make sure the permissions for those files are set to allow access while the device is locked; and (b) doesn’t exceed CPU allowances by making sure the request has `requiresExternalPower` is set to `true` to turn off the CPU monitor.

Comment: @Rob I edited my post, i hope this gives you a better view

Comment: Yes, that helps. I would suggest adding a log statement in the expiration handler, so you can see if it is called. (An unrelated aside, but your operation isn’t cancelable, so there’s no point in trying to cancel it. And your routine is synchronous, so the completion handler pattern doesn’t really make sense. But neither of those would appear to be relevant to the issue at hand.) But external power setting is great. The fact that you’re not marking the task completed prematurely is good. I guess I’d start single-stepping in the encryption and see if you can figure out where it’s freezing.

Comment: @Rob I wanted to make the decryption async, but it seemed like that wasn’t possible with RNCryptor. But i will try to look what goes wrong.

Comment: I would expect the above code to crash (and to have compiler warnings). `NSData *mpDecryptedData = [RNDecryptor decryptData:self withPassword:theMasterPassword error:&firstStatus];`. At this point `self` is the UIApplicationDelegate isn't it, not NSData? I'm having trouble figuring out where the actual data would come from. Is the data large or small?

Comment: @Rob I updated the post with some new information.

Comment: @RobNapier This is a simplified version of my code, i just took the last code and put it directly in the AppDelegate to show how I set up my BGTask.
I updated the post with some new information.

Btw. the data isn't big, Its about 150 KB encrypted

Comment: That's the most expensive of the operations, so it's definitely the point when the system might spike the CPU. But it should be substantially less than 100ms. One experiment would be to remove the calls to RNCryptor and replace them with an `[[NSThread currentThread] sleepForTimeInterval: 0.5];` and then also replacing it with a piece of busy code (counting to a 100 trillion or the like). That would explore whether it's due to a CPU spike or a timeout.

Comment: You can also simplify the code, keeping RNCryptor in the loop a little bit, by just calling the `+keyForPassword:` method. Just trying to separate the calls to CommonCrypto vs other things that are time consuming. I would also try changing the rounds to 1 rather than 10000, which will speed up RNCryptor by a few orders of magnitude (it won't decrypt correctly, but you'll see it's the time/cpu that's the problem). You can edit this line: https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor-objc/blob/4cffc43be0487fc7e884a11085a89b2061b748d4/RNCryptor/RNCryptor.m#L49  (and the one a few lines later)

Comment: @RobNapier I just changed the round to 1 and this does indeed make the app not freeze anymore. The data is empty as you said.

Comment: So it's either the amount of time or the amount of CPU; I'm not completely clear about Apple's current rules for background processing resources. PBKDF2 is intentionally very expensive to compute. Depending on your actual needs, you may be able to switch to key-based encryption rather than using a password (RNCryptor supports that). Key-based encryption is very fast.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215390/discussion-between-john-and-rob-napier).